# Core Foundation and ARC

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I have a property like this in a UIView subclass

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) CTTypesetterRef typesetter;
```

I initiate the TypeSetter in the view constructor:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andAttributedString:(NSMutableAttributedString * )   pageAttributedString
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
            self.attributedString = pageAttributedString;
            self.typesetter = CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)CFBridgingRetain(self.attributedString));
}
```

The question is where to release the TypeSetter using CFRelease?

I am using ARC, IOS 7 and Xcode 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `-dealloc` like you would do with MRR.

just remember that unlike MRR, in ARC you don't have to call `[super dealloc]` neither do you need to explicitely call `-release` on your ARC managed ivars.

Comment: Well you DO need to implement dealloc for releasing CF type properties. This is not highly visible but a requirement for ARC as ARC does not manage memory for non Objective-C objects.

Comment: I think it's what I just said ;) CF type properties are one kind of non ARC managed ivars, and you have to deal with their lifetime yourself.

Oh and when I wrote "you don't need to call `-release`" I meant for real, you don't have to set your ARC managed ivars to nil yourself, ARC will do that. you actually can't call `-release` on your ivars ;)

Comment: You are correct JTAS, I fixed the problem, I referenced a parent view in its sub layer using a strong property, so that dealloc was never called

    @property(nonatomic, strong) CoreTextView * coreTextView;
The correct is 
    @property(nonatomic, weak) CoreTextView * coreTextView;

So the right place to release is dealloc. Thank you